# Too many KDC calls from KafkaConsumer on Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kerberos, kafka-consumer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a standalone (master=local for its own reasons) Spark structured streaming application that reads from kerberized kafka cluster.
It works functionally, but it makes too many calls to KDC to fetch TGS for each micro-batch execution.
Either with `useTicketCache=true` or by providing keytab in the jaas config, the behavior was same - it bombarded KDC for each broker for each task.
Spark seemed to fetch the TGT correctly from the cache whereas TGS was not reused across multiple runs towards the same broker.
When trying to look at debug logs, it shows below message before fetching TGS

```
Found ticket for UPN/DOMAIN@REALM to go to krbtgt/DOMAIN@REALM expiring on Thu Jul 23 09:08:39 CEST 2020
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
```

Am I missing any spark configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with Kerberos configuration.
We accidentally had `useSubjectCredsOnly=false` in the System property.

Removing it (the default is true) fixed the problem.

Ref : sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.java in JDK code